# ansible-playbook - How to replace text in multiple dest

Tags: ansible

Here is my script. I want to replace text in multiple dest. How I can use wildcard in (dest=/home/*/conf/server.xml).

```
- hosts: 192.168.8.11
  user: mohitmehral
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
   - replace:
       dest=/home/5/conf/server.xml
       #dest=/home/1/conf/server.xml
       #dest=/home/2/conf/server.xml
       #dest=/home/3/conf/server.xml
       #dest=/home/4/conf/server.xml
       #dest=/home/5/conf/server.xml
       regexp='pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %t %a %p %v %q &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; %m &quot;%U&quot; &quot;%S&quot; &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; %b %s %D"/>'
       replace='pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %t %a %p %v %q&quot;%{Referer}i&quot; %m &quot;%U&quot; &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; &quot;%b&quot; &quot;%s&quot; &quot;%D&quot;"/>'
       backup=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

If the regex and replace pattern are same, then you can do like this:

```
- hosts: 192.168.8.11
  user: mohitmehral
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
   - replace:
       dest="/home/{{ item }}/conf/server.xml"
       regexp='pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %t %a %p %v %q &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; %m &quot;%U&quot; &quot;%S&quot; &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; %b %s %D"/>'
       replace='pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %t %a %p %v %q&quot;%{Referer}i&quot; %m &quot;%U&quot; &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; &quot;%b&quot; &quot;%s&quot; &quot;%D&quot;"/>'
       backup=yes
     with_items: [1,2,3,4,5]
```